# Linker error when using gSOAP with 2 different wsdl files

Tags: c++, gsoap

I am writing a C++ web service client using gSOAP on linux using 2 separate wsdl files in the same application. I have managed to get things working with just one wsdl file, and after reading documentation, went through the process of using wsdl2h on both files:

```
    wsdl2h -o header.h wsdlfile1.wsdl wsdlfile2.wsdl
```

This worked fine and so I then did

```
    soapcpp2 -i -I/usr/share/gsoap/import/ header.h
```

I then did all the usual namespace modifications in the typemap.dat as instructed. I now find that I have two .cpp and .h files of the type soapService1Proxy.cpp/h and soapService2Proxy.cpp/h. This is not quite what I expected, but regardless, I included both headers in my main function and created instances of each Proxy class and used in exactly the same way as I did for with just one wsdl file. I then compile with

```
    g++ -DWITH_OPENSSL main.cpp soapC.cpp soapService1Proxy.cpp soapService2Proxy.cpp -lgsoapssl++ -lssl
```

which returns the error

```
    /tmp/ccHNDAM4.o:(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `namespaces'
    /tmp/ccLJIHwV.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I know that the  'namepaces' refers to the array in the .nsmap files (which in this case are identical for each wsdl). I have included only one of these as the compiler complains of multiple definition if I include both. I really would appreciate it if anyone could tell me what I am doing wrong here as I have tried to follow the guidelines and gSOAP docs as faithfully as possible but simply cannot resolve this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never used SOAP but I had a quick look at [this user guide](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soapdoc2.html).

The last paragraph in [section 7.1.4](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soapdoc2.html#tth_sEc7.1.4) says that the `-n` and `-p` options to `soapcpp2` help to resolve link conflicts. The link there to [section 19.35](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soapdoc2.html#sec%3acodenamespace) provides more information. It appears you have to run `wsdl2h` on each file separately using the `-q` option to provide a C++ namespace for each one. When you then run `soapcpp2` it will automatically apply `-p` and all you have to do is supply `-n` to have the `namespaces` array prefixed with your C++ namespace name followed by an underscore.

I haven't tried any of this but hopefully that will be enough to 
get you going again.